# Updating ObservableCollections in WPF MVVM Applications

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I am trying to implement a 'message/comments' display.

The view consists of a ListBox which is bound to an ObservableCollection(these are the posts).  I am also two-way binding the ListBox's SelectedItem.

The replies for the currently selected post are also stored in another ObservableCollection.  Every item in this collection should be inserted into Posts collection, immediately after the selected message.

Everything in the properties updates fine.  Its when these lists gets rendered that feces hits the fan.

everytime a new post is selected, I have to do '.Insert()' rather than '.Add().'  this has significant [unacceptable] performance penalties even when handling several thousand posts and several hundred comments.

I would like to do this: 'PostsCollection = newObservableCollectionWithPostsAndComments', but that causes the entire listbox to refresh and the SelectedItem to become unselected.

How are you supposed to handle dynamically inserting items into an ObservableCollection<> that is bound to a ListBox without repainting the Listbox?

*aside from the new items being displayed

EDIT:  I have a slight feeling that I've made a coding error, but I can't show all of the source code here.  If you could tell me if what I want is even possible, that'd be great.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a sample test code which replicates the issue you are facing

Comment: what happens when you use an `ICollectionView` and bind to it, then sort descending?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem you have issues with the insert of items in the Observable collection. Indeed, after each insert the collection calls the collection changed event and the UI is redrawn.

One way to solve it is to derive a new class from Observable Collection like ObservableCollectionEx with methods like AddRange(IEnumerable items) in which you will add multiple items to the collection but raise only one collection changed event. The example is on the link below

http://xcalibursystems.com/2013/12/making-a-better-observablecollection-part-1-extensions/

Other way, perhaps not a clean one, is to create new ObservableCollection with the resulting set of items and assign it to the property to which ItemsSource of ListBox binds. Also don't forget to raise PropertyChanged event for that property if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged